# Contractibility of the total space of the infinite tautological bundle minus the zero section

Tags: general-topology

There is a [tautological line bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_line_bundle) $L$ on the infinite dimensional projective space $\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ with total space $L=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{RP}^\infty\times \mathbb{R}^\infty\mid v\in x\}$ and zero-section $z:\mathbb{RP}^\infty\to L$.

Is the space $L\setminus (\operatorname{Im }z)$ contractible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. $L \setminus \mathrm{Im} z$ could be identified with $\mathbb{R}^\infty\setminus \{0\}$, where $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a direct limit of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. only finitely many coordinates are non-zero. This space deformationally retracts to the usual $S^\infty$, which is contractible.

Comment: Dear @Dmitry, thank you for the answer. Is it possible to give a concrete retraction formula?

Comment: $tx + (1-t) \cdot \frac{x}{||x||}$ ? Just a linear homotopy between original point and its projection on a sphere. This linear combination is never zero, so it's correctly defined map $\mathbb{R}^\infty\times I \to \mathbb{R}^\infty$.